# Upload Photo in Flex, set the URLRequest

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

In my Flex Application doing Image upload for local system.

Actually i'm using `FileReference` class in this class have `load()` it is only in `FP-10`.

so i'm doing another way using `upload()` but this method taking `URLRequest` object.

```
 private const FILE_UPLOAD_URL:String
fileRef.upload(new URLRequest(FILE_UPLOAD_URL));
```

so problem is how to get file url in local system..

give me example for this help lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Uploader{
    private var fileReference:FileReference;
    private static const FILE_UPLOAD_URL:String = "http://somewebsite.com/images/..."

    public function Uploader()
    {
        fileReference = new FileReference();
        fileReference.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);
    }   

    //Call this method to start browsing on local filesystem
    private function doUpload():void
    {
        fileReference.browse();
    }

    //After selecting a file you can now upload it 
    private function onFileSelect():void
    {
        fileReference.upload(new URLRequest(FILE_UPLOAD_URL));
    }

}
```

A full, working example can be found [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/21/uploading-files-in-flex-using-the-filereference-class/)

Also make sure to check out the [Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_7.html) on this matter

Cheers